# Vim BufWritePost not taking effect until vimrc is sourced manually on startup

Tags: vim

Using a minimal vimrc to remove trailing whitespace.

```
set list                            " show invisible characters
set listchars=trail:·               " display extra whitespace

autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> :%s/\s\+$//e
```

When I open a project and start working on a file with trailing white space when I save the file I expect it to be removed, but it doesn't get removed.

When I source `.vimrc` manually and save the file it suddenly works.

What is causing this and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

`BufWritePost` is executed **after** writing. You don't need to source `.vimrc` — you can just write the second time.

But to really fix the problem use `BufWritePre`.

Comment: I've changed to `BufWritePre` and it still isn't working, no matter how many times I save the file it doesn't remove the trailing whitespace until I source my `.vimrc` file

Comment: Are you sure `vim` sources your `.vimrc`? Try `:scriptnames`

Comment: I've just checked and it does source it, it's the first one in the list.

Comment: If I do `:autocmd BufWritePre` nothing shows up, but as soon as I source the file and run it again it appears. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea. Your minimal `.vimrc` works for me — `autocmd BufWritePost` show the command and works in the way I described: it removes trailing spaces on the second save.

Comment: Could it be some scripts sourced later remove all `BufWritePost` autocommands? Or may be all? Try to put the autocmd into `~/.vim/after/spaces.vim`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189742/discussion-between-assertcarl-and-phd).

Answer (score 0):

From Vim documentation:

```
7. Buffer-local autocommands    *autocmd-buflocal* *autocmd-buffer-local*
                    *<buffer=N>* *<buffer=abuf>* *E680*

Buffer-local autocommands are attached to a specific buffer.  They are useful
if the buffer does not have a name and when the name does not match a specific
pattern.  But it also means they must be explicitly added to each buffer.

Instead of a pattern buffer-local autocommands use one of these forms:
    <buffer>    current buffer
    <buffer=99> buffer number 99
    <buffer=abuf>   using <abuf> (only when executing autocommands)
            |<abuf>|
```

Of course `.vimrc` is only ever sourced once when `vim` starts, at that time the current buffer is not your file.

Solution: replace `<buffer>` with `*`.